# Multi-Level Serving Tree vs Directed Acyclic Graph

Tags: distributed-computing, impala, presto, directed-acyclic-graphs

At "Big Data Concepts, Theories, and Applications", I found a [brief decription](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=WMGuCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43&dq=multi-level%20serving%20tree%20vs%20dag&source=bl&ots=1TFjdGIFVZ&sig=ACfU3U3JgHrV5nRnna7yDrO0gc2g84A7jA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiK_dXZvcHlAhWh1aYKHbdVDgcQ6AEwEnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=multi-level%20serving%20tree%20vs%20dag&f=false) of MLST and DAG. Still the description doesn't provide an answer to *WHY one distributed systems use MLST while other use DAG? What does that mean in terms of performance/latency/multi-user/etc.?*

I noticed that DAG is used by distributed computational engines (i.e. Apache Spark, Storm, Tez) while MLST is used by interactional distributed databases (i.e. Google Dremel, Apache Impala, Presto). *Is this always true?*

Comment: I can't speak about distributed systems' architectural choices in general, but for context, here's the paper about design of Presto SQL: https://prestosql.io/paper